# How to take sql server backup for this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups, database-restore

My client having the SQL server 2008 cloud version as test server where, we deployed the sql database of my application.This deployment done before 7 month. Since while testing application during these 7 months, client added lot of data. But according to new requirements 
we added number of tables and columns in existing tables at our end. Now I want to update Client test server database but his data should not affect. What is the right way to backup and restore these updates from development server to client's test server. we are having sql server 2008 R2 as development server.

Comment: Which Visual Studio do you use? Are you using dacpacs? If so, test the dacpac on a copy of the client database if the results are positive then deploy the dacpac on the client server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a plan. For example we do it like this:

```
1. Compare 2 databases with some compare tool(we use RedGate)
2. Generate migration scripts for structure that will update database structure
3. Generate migration scripts for data that will update new columns and will fill classification tables etc.
4. Take full backup before applying migration scripts
5. Run migration scripts
6. Update App version on clients if necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks. But RedGate or any other tool is prohibited to install on client's Machine. any other way that sql server can handle this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to say that you do not have backup of version of database which is currently on your client's machine? Then it is your fault I think. Can't you backup one of production database?

Comment: No, you are getting me other way. my comment is regarding client's terms will not allow to install any tool to manage source control for sql server. it is out of my scope or you can say it is not allowed.

Comment: You want to update client database structure. You should know current structure of client's database to compare with your development database. Without 2 databases you can not produce migration scripts. So you can go to one of your client, restore copy of client's database, delete all operational data from that database and bring that empty database to your work. Then compare structures an produce appropriate scripts. Without production and development database how can you do this? I don't know. And don't forget to make backup of your development database after its migration to production!

Comment: Can you please guide me how to write migrations script please ?

Comment: You simply compare two databases with some comparing tool like RedGate SQL Compare and write scripts that should update production  database structure. Say you have table TEST(c1 int) on your production and you have changed it in your development database on TEST(c1 int, c2 int) then you simply create script like Alter Table TEST add c2 int. And you do this for all differences. Also you do this for any classification data in your database.

Comment: Absolutely right. but RatGate is already expensive and client cannot afford. and other limitation I already explain in my earlier comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68868/discussion-between-liladhar-and-giorgi-nakeuri).